# MacBook Pro - Why does the keyboard/trackpad being plugged in cause reboot loop?

Tags: keyboard, reboot, touchpad, macbook-pro, infinite-loop

I came here because I wasn't sure if this is a question for StackOverflow.
My friend's MacBook Pro was/is stuck in an infinite reboot loop. We would see the apple logo and the loading bar for a good second or two before it ends up rebooting all over again.

We tried to run it in Recovery Mode, Safe Mode, Single User Mode, Network Mode, and even tried running a fresh install of MacOS off of a USB... but MacOS would just end up rebooting anyway. We ended up watching a YouTube tutorial of a guy who had the same problem, and what he did was remove his internal keyboard/trackpad through the inner hardware. Desperately, we ended up doing that as well, not expecting for it to work. But surprisingly, it ended up working but was **A LOT** slower on boot. We thought it would end up working again, if we turn it back off and plug in the trackpad/keyboard but it just goes back into an infinite loop unless we keep this internal hardware unplugged.

I'm glad his MacBook is *somewhat* working again, but what is causing this to happen? Is it because of an EFI issue? I don't really use Macs personally but this is just such a weird thing to witness...

Comment: Have cou checked if one of the "magic" boot keys is stuck? (e.g. C, T, ...)

Comment: @EugenRieck we ended up going through the partitions only to find that his MacOS-HD and MacOS-HD Data partitions were unmounted. The only mounted partition was his Bootcamp Windows. It kinda makes sense to me that he was in a boot loop, but I'm still confused why it's working barely just by removing the internal keyboard/trackpad.

Comment: The "magic" keys will e.g. chose a different boot volume ...